# What's known on genetic factors that explain behavioral differences between human males and females?

Tags: genetics, behaviour, psychology, sexual-dimorphism, human

Long story short: women are from Venus and men are from Mars. But how much of the differences arose from evolution and how much of it comes from Venusian and Martian cultural differences?

Jokes aside, I'm looking for an overview of which social-behavioural differences science has already pinpointed to be rooted in evolution.

update: [this article is a great starting point](https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/articles/201711/the-truth-about-sex-differences)

[This question also pertains to psychology, therefore I also asked a related question there.](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/21548/do-women-naturally-form-groups-to-defend-themselves)

Comment: There are many behavioral differences which are hypothesized to have an evolutionary basis, and which many evolutionary psychologists believe are strongly supported by the evidence. But you have a wrong view of science. There will never be a time when something is "proven," it can only be that more and more people accept something on the basis of compelling evidence. No matter how much evidence there is, a sociologist can always say that they aren't convinced.

Comment: In addition to that it's well possible that a given difference both has a evolutionary basis/root (however tiny it may be) and was expanded into a larger social construct.

Comment: @Nicolai Or be shrinked by social influence. In other words, it is possible for a sex difference to exist *in spite* (not *because*) of social influence. Personally, I think that this is probably quite common.

Comment: This overview paper should help you, it is a review of known differences. http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/12330/12626747/myanthropologylibrary/PDF/NDS_41_Ember_50.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that you can conclude something is not socially constructed because it has "an evolutionary basis". Social constructs and changes in allele frequencies are not mutually exclusive, nor is one less real than the other.

Comment: How statistical of a difference are you looking for? no behavior is going to be universal and exlusive to all men/women. The quick and dirty way of telling is to see which behavior are universal across cultures, not perfect but probably your best bet. I seem to remember that, males are more likely to commit homicide and women are more talkative in every culture studied. but this is purely from memory and I cant remember if it was by sex or gender. .

Comment: I would like to have more precision in this question. What are "males" and "females", and what is the difference between them genetically? You can trivially say XX/XY, but there are plenty of karyotypes that fit into one of the traditional sexes without even getting into gender identity. Then there are male/female/nonbinary gender identities, which are imperfectly correlated with karyotype, but nonetheless adhere somewhat to traditional "sex" behaviors. One can obviously point to developmental characters (secondary sexual characteristics such as hormones), but that's a bit tautological IMO.

Answer (score 1):

***Short Answers***

- At least one personality trait (neuroticism) works differently between males and females on a genetic basis.
- The effect of Testosterone on male behavior (aggression, reproduction, self-maintenance) is deeply rooted in vertebrate evolution, while it is proven that testosterone controls behaviour in human males as well. (Only males produce large amounts of testosterone)

### Connecting Personality Traits to Male/Female -Genetics

David pointed out that an explicit connection to evolution is not necessary to explain genetical differences in male/female behavior.

[Weisberg et al. 2011](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51594567_Gender_Differences_in_Personality_across_the_Ten_Aspects_of_the_Big_Five) have mapped the "big five" personality traits to males and females. So the martian and venusian aspects of personality can be quantified.

[South et al. 2018 (paywall)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0092656618300321) did perform twin studies to find a genetic basis for sex differences in the big five. As far as I understood, they did not find any genetic differences between males and females.

[Wendt et al. 2022](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2022.03.03.22271772v1.full) however looked specifically at the trait Neuroticism. Neuroticism can be understood as the *likelihood of a person to **worry** about something*. It's not a disease or psychological condition, it's just one of the "big five" personality traits.

> Gene expression variation in the pituitary was enriched for neuroticism loci in males (males β=0.026, P=0.002) and genetically-regulated transcriptomic changes highlighted the effect of RAB7L1, TEX26, and PLOT1.[...] this study identified several molecular pathways that can partially explain the known sex differences in neurotic symptoms and their psychiatric comorbidities.

### Testosterone Affects Every Vertebrate, including Humans

Testosterone heavily affects human male personality, mood, behaviour, etc. ([Zitzmann 2020](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/andr.12867)). This might come from mechanisms that are essential for the survival of every vertebrate species.

---

**Testosterone's impact on Mating Habits is Conserved within all Vertebrates**

Testosterone is the key modulator of male mating habits (which may influence socio-behavioral differences between males/females more than we like to admit): [Husak et al. 2021 (paywall)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33755201/)

> We study this topic by assessing how various social and environmental dynamics influence testosterone levels across the
> entire vertebrate tree of life. Our analyses show that breeding season length and mating system are the strongest predictors of average testosterone concentrations, whereas breeding season length, environmental temperature, and variability in precipitation are
> the strongest predictors of within-population variation in testosterone.

---

**Testosterone may be too Deeply Rooted in Animal Physiology to ever be Changed at all**

Here's another paper, ([Hau 2007 (paywall)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17226801/)):

> Mechanistically, trade-offs result from the need to differentially allocate limited resources to traits like reproduction versus self-maintenance. [...]. The hormone testosterone may mediate life-history trade-offs due to its pleiotropic actions in male vertebrates. Conservation in the actions of testosterone in vertebrates has prompted the 'evolutionary constraint hypothesis,' which assumes that testosterone signaling mechanisms and male traits evolve as a unit. This hypothesis implies that the actions of testosterone are similar across sexes and species, and only the levels of circulating testosterone concentrations change during evolution. In contrast, the 'evolutionary potential hypothesis' proposes that testosterone signaling mechanisms and **male traits** evolve independently.

When I look up *"evolutionary constraint hypothesis"* (if I understood correctly) it states that testosterone signalling has established a deep connection to multiple target tissues. This connection is so deep, that one trait's connection to testosterone can not evolve without affecting another. That's why the effect of hormones is so conserved among animals in general ([Ketterson & Nolan 1999 (Paywall)](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/10.1086/303280), [McGlothlin & Ketterson 2007](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2606720/)).

Others think that testosterone derived traits are not constrained and can evolve (in part) independently from another (‘evolutionary potential hypothesis').

Overall, one can not evaluate much raw data, since all these papers are behind a paywall. Nevertheless, the papers cited here show that there are very strong opinions that testosterone determines male traits/behavior and that this can control vertebrate evolution.

But like I said, that does not totally exclude cultural factors.

Comment: You say in a post on Meta that many questions about evolution are rather about differences. It seems to me that this is an obvious case. The question is simply nature v. nurture, or more technically, are there social-behavioural differences between the sexes that have a **genetic** basis. If there are differences with a genetic basis they obviously evolved, so talking about evolution is obscuring the real issue. Your answer does not provide the sort of objective answer I consider required — such and such a behavioural trait is determined by such and such a gene(s).

Comment: If there is a genetic basis it evolved, yes, but do specific narratives exist in the literature that  illustrate the evolutionary nature of male/female differences in behavior? — my attempt is definitely not a good one BUT I had fun writing it and I hope that others find better narratives than I did, since I am very much interested in how much cultural and how much inherited factors determine our behavior

Comment: @David - I see your point, one can remove the „evolution“ part of this question and it would still make sense. So it‘d be enough to point at genetic differences between males and females, filter out behavior-associated genes, and then the question would be answered?

Comment: I think so. Although on reflection regulatory genes may affect the extent of testosterone release and hence aggression in different societies. One could argue about what caused this in some societies and not others, but I suspect we don’t have much info on these genes, much less the influences on their selection, if indeed this occurred.

Comment: I think that in the age of NGS and Cambridge Analytica I expect there to be studies that associate SNPs to the big five personality traits *and* distinguish between males and females.

Comment: I found something and edited my answer. Should I delete the testosterone part?

Comment: You can edit your answer to improve it as you feel fit, especially if nobody has upvoted it yet. I tend to do so myself if I think it needs changing, even if it has votes. I generally draw attention to this and invite voters to reassess (although they don't). One generally piece of — I hope — constructive criticism. It helps the reader if you can start with a summary when one's answer is quite extensive. Just call it "summary" or "Short Answer", but please not the internet slang expression. It prepares the reader for your argument and lets him decide whether he wants to read it.

Comment: Alrighty. Applied your tips. Also changed the header and tags of the original question

Comment: Re: my comment on question, I am still not sure what a genetic difference between males and females is. Testosterone expression does not equate to male/female stuff. Who are males and who are females? Are you respecting peoples' gender identities? You will get quite different answers depending on whether you take a gender essentialist view vs. a more nuanced view of gender. **I think that you should take gender identity into account, but that also makes the question a lot harder to answer.** What happens when the same person presents different gender identities / behaviors?

Comment: I see your point. So gender is what one identifies with, and sex is the biological sex, right? So if I replace "male/female" with "sex" in my answer, this should solve the issue, right?